# Deploy JSF App on Openshift DIY Tomcat not working

Tags: java, git, jsf, tomcat, openshift

I created a DIY cartridge on Openshift using this git repo:
https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-tomcat-quickstart

After that I did the following additional things:

- configured the Tomcat to run with a JDK 7u72 by setting up an setenv.sh to the bin directory
- removed the ROOT app from Tomcat

Since I've done this I try to deploy my JSF2 app on this tomcat. The process of deployment works, I've succsessfully deployed a very simple JSF App.

My app comes with lots of 3rd party JARs and some Java EE features. The deployment process (git push) tells no errors or exceptions. The ../logs/catalina.out tells no errors or exceptions. The ../logs/catalina[...].log tells no errors or exceptions.

To determine the problem I created a simple JFS App which has nothing but a starting page but all the needed librarys of my original App. When i call this App after deployment I get the following exception:

---

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at tc-usvtudd.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

---

On the second call the server only says service not available. I've no more Idea what I could check or change to get this deployment working. It seems that it has something to do with the additional JARs but I can not get any further information about the problem.

Every response is welcome :)

Kind regards